# Patterns for dealing with variadic arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, variadic-functions

I usually do something like the following when dealing with variadic arguments in JavaScript:

```
var f = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  // ...
  return something;
};
```

But what about doing instead:

```
var f = function() {
  return (function(self, args) {
    // ...
    return something; 
  }(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
};
```

I couldn't readily find anything addressing the pattern above, so I decided to post it here. Before I start experimenting with it, I would like to know if **there are any flaws or risks** I could be missing when using the rather unusual patterns described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the pattern to be slightly less readable than the first, but it lets me write longer one-liners without declaring variables so I am growing fond of it.

```
  Object.defineProperty(RegExp, 'join', {
    value: function() {
      return (function(regexes, last) {
        return RegExp(regexes.map(function(item) {
          return item.source;
        }).reduce(function(prev, next) {
          return prev + next;
        }), last.slice(last.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
      }(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0),
      arguments[arguments.length - 1]+''));
    }, enumerable: false
  });
```